# getting string between 2 characters in python

Tags: python, string, function, character, extract

I need to get certain words out from a string in to a new format. For example, I call the function with the input:

```
text2function('$sin (x)$ is an function of x')
```

and I need to put them into a StringFunction:

```
StringFunction(function, independent_variables=[vari])
```

where I need to get just 'sin (x)' for function and 'x' for vari. So it would look like this finally:

```
StringFunction('sin (x)', independent_variables=['x']
```

problem is, I can't seem to obtain function and vari. I have tried:

```
start = string.index(start_marker) + len(start_marker)
end = string.index(end_marker, start)
return string[start:end]
```

and

```
r = re.compile('$()$')
m = r.search(string)
if m:
     lyrics = m.group(1)
```

and

```
send = re.findall('$([^"]*)$',string)
```

all seems to seems to give me nothing. Am I doing something wrong? All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Tweeky way!

```
>>> char1 = '('
>>> char2 = ')'
>>> mystr = "mystring(123234sample)"
>>> print mystr[mystr.find(char1)+1 : mystr.find(char2)]
123234sample
```

Comment: I really like this solution for what I am doing.

Comment: Great solution! I incorporated it as a lambda for easy re-use: GetValue = lambda mystr: mystr[mystr.find(char1) + 1 : mystr.find(char2)]

Comment: This demonstrates a good base solution but does not cover potential false-positives. If the string is not validated before hand you get bad results. my)string(123sample) or mystring(123sample\  would return strings that are likely not what you want.  Using str.index() in this case would flag corrupt data (i.e. "mystring(example)")

Answer (score 9):

`$` is a special character in regex (it denotes the end of the string). You need to escape it:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\$(.*?)\$', '$sin (x)$ is an function of x')
['sin (x)']
```

Comment: what does `r` stands for do we need it?

Comment: raw string, so that it treats `\` as an escape character

Answer (score 8):

If you want to cut a string between two identical characters (i.e, !234567890!)
you can use

```
   line_word = line.split('!')
   print (line_word[1])
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to start searching for the second character *beyond* `start`:

```
end = string.index(end_marker, start + 1)
```

because otherwise it'll find the same character at the same location again:

```
>>> start_marker = end_marker = '$'
>>> string = '$sin (x)$ is an function of x'
>>> start = string.index(start_marker) + len(start_marker)
>>> end = string.index(end_marker, start + 1)
>>> string[start:end]
'sin (x)'
```

For your regular expressions, the `$` character is interpreted as an anchor, not the literal character. Escape it to match the literal `$` (and look for things that are *not* `$` instead of not `"`:

```
send = re.findall('\$([^$]*)\$', string)
```

which gives:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\$([^$]*)\$', string)
['sin (x)']
```

The regular expression `$()$` otherwise doesn't really match anything between the parenthesis even if you did escape the `$` characters.